# Top of the pop-

Tags: javascript, animation, popup, alert

My goal is to have a popup on an error/success event, into an ajax multiple post requests.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://2.162.45.201/api/profile/'+basicprofile+'/recall',
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function () { alert('Configuration chargée : Régie'); },
    error: function (){ alert('error'); }
    });
```

So I want to replace the alert popup by the following popup

```js
"use strict";

function makeAlert(t) {
  function e(t, e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      t.classList.remove(n), t.className = "wf-alert-box animated " + o, t.className = "wf-alert-box animated " + o + " transitionTrick"
    }, e), setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("alertBtns").removeChild(a)
    }, e + 1500)
  }
  var a = document.createElement("div"),
    n = (document.createElement("i"), t.getAttribute("data-animate-start")),
    o = t.getAttribute("data-animate-end"),
    r = t.getAttribute("data-text-color"),
    l = t.getAttribute("data-bg-color"),
    i = t.getAttribute("data-placement"),
    c = document.getElementById("alertBtns"),
    d = document.createTextNode(t.getAttribute("data-content"));
  a.className = " wf-alert-box animated " + n, a.appendChild(d), c.appendChild(a), c.className = i, a.style.color = r, a.style.backgroundColor = l, e(a, 3500);
  for (var m = document.querySelectorAll(".wf-alert-box i"), s = 0; s < m.length; s++) m[s].addEventListener("click", function() {
    e(this.parentElement, 0)
  })
}
var topVal = 0,
  alertBoxoffsetHeight = 0,
  alertBoxLastChild = 0,
  alertBoxoffsetTop = 20;
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";.wf-alert-box{max-width:250px;background:#000;padding:30px;color:#fff;position:relative;z-index:9999;text-transform:capitalize;text-align:center;font-weight:700;-webkit-box-shadow:0 29px 77px -23px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-moz-box-shadow:0 29px 77px -23px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 29px 77px -23px rgba(0,0,0,.2);margin-bottom:20px;overflow:hidden;max-height:300px}.wf-alert-box i{position:absolute;top:0;right:0}#alertBtns{position:fixed;max-width:250px}#alertBtns.right{right:25px}#alertBtns.left{left:25px}#alertBtns.center{margin:0 auto;left:0;right:0}.transitionTrick{transition:padding .3s,margin .3s,max-height .1s;-webkit-transition:padding .3s,margin .3s,max-height .1s;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0}.wf-alert-btn{background:#47b2f1;padding:10px 20px;border:0;cursor:pointer;color:#fff;outline:0;box-shadow:0 5px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);-webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);-moz-box-shadow:0 5px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);transition:all .3s;-webkit-transition:all .3s}.wf-alert-btn:hover{box-shadow:0 5px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);-webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);-moz-box-shadow:0 5px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4)}.animated{animation-duration:.5s;animation-fill-mode:both}.animated.infinite{animation-iteration-count:infinite}.animated.hinge{animation-duration:2s}.animated.bounceIn,.animated.bounceOut,.animated.flipOutX,.animated.flipOutY{animation-duration:.75s}@keyframes bounce{20%,53%,80%,from,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}40%,43%{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.755,.050,.855,.060);transform:translate3d(0,-30px,0)}70%{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.755,.050,.855,.060);transform:translate3d(0,-15px,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(0,-4px,0)}}.bounce{animation-name:bounce;transform-origin:center bottom}@keyframes flash{50%,from,to{opacity:1}25%,75%{opacity:0}}.flash{animation-name:flash}@keyframes pulse{from{transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}50%{transform:scale3d(1.05,1.05,1.05)}to{transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}}.pulse{animation-name:pulse}@keyframes rubberBand{from{transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}30%{transform:scale3d(1.25,.75,1)}40%{transform:scale3d(.75,1.25,1)}50%{transform:scale3d(1.15,.85,1)}65%{transform:scale3d(.95,1.05,1)}75%{transform:scale3d(1.05,.95,1)}to{transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}}.rubberBand{animation-name:rubberBand}@keyframes shake{from,to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}10%,30%,50%,70%,90%{transform:translate3d(-10px,0,0)}20%,40%,60%,80%{transform:translate3d(10px,0,0)}}.shake{animation-name:shake}@keyframes headShake{0%{transform:translateX(0)}6.5%{transform:translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg)}18.5%{transform:translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg)}31.5%{transform:translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg)}43.5%{transform:translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg)}50%{transform:translateX(0)}}.headShake{animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;animation-name:headShake}@keyframes swing{20%{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,15deg)}40%{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-10deg)}60%{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,5deg)}80%{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-5deg)}to{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg)}}.swing{transform-origin:top center;animation-name:swing}@keyframes tada{from{transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}10%,20%{transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9) rotate3d(0,0,1,-3deg)}30%,50%,70%,90%{transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1) rotate3d(0,0,1,3deg)}40%,60%,80%{transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1) rotate3d(0,0,1,-3deg)}to{transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}}.tada{animation-name:tada}@keyframes wobble{from{transform:none}15%{transform:translate3d(-25%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,-5deg)}30%{transform:translate3d(20%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,3deg)}45%{transform:translate3d(-15%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,-3deg)}60%{transform:translate3d(10%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,2deg)}75%{transform:translate3d(-5%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,-1deg)}to{transform:none}}.wobble{animation-name:wobble}@keyframes jello{11.1%,from,to{transform:none}22.2%{transform:skewX(-12.5deg) skewY(-12.5deg)}33.3%{transform:skewX(6.25deg) skewY(6.25deg)}44.4%{transform:skewX(-3.125deg) skewY(-3.125deg)}55.5%{transform:skewX(1.5625deg) skewY(1.5625deg)}66.6%{transform:skewX(-.78125deg) skewY(-.78125deg)}77.7%{transform:skewX(.390625deg) skewY(.390625deg)}88.8%{transform:skewX(-.1953125deg) skewY(-.1953125deg)}}.jello{animation-name:jello;transform-origin:center}@keyframes bounceIn{20%,40%,60%,80%,from,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}20%{transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1)}40%{transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(1.03,1.03,1.03)}80%{transform:scale3d(.97,.97,.97)}to{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}}.bounceIn{animation-name:bounceIn}@keyframes bounceInDown{60%,75%,90%,from,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-3000px,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,25px,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(0,-10px,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(0,5px,0)}to{transform:none}}.bounceInDown{animation-name:bounceInDown}@keyframes bounceInLeft{60%,75%,90%,from,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-3000px,0,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(25px,0,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(-10px,0,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(5px,0,0)}to{transform:none}}.bounceInLeft{animation-name:bounceInLeft}@keyframes bounceInRight{60%,75%,90%,from,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(3000px,0,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(-25px,0,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(10px,0,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(-5px,0,0)}to{transform:none}}.bounceInRight{animation-name:bounceInRight}@keyframes bounceInUp{60%,75%,90%,from,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,3000px,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,-20px,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(0,10px,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(0,-5px,0)}to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}}.bounceInUp{animation-name:bounceInUp}@keyframes bounceOut{20%{transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9)}50%,55%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}}.bounceOut{animation-name:bounceOut}@keyframes bounceOutDown{20%{transform:translate3d(0,10px,0)}40%,45%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,-20px,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)}}.bounceOutDown{animation-name:bounceOutDown}@keyframes bounceOutLeft{20%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(20px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-2000px,0,0)}}.bounceOutLeft{animation-name:bounceOutLeft}@keyframes bounceOutRight{20%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(-20px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(2000px,0,0)}}.bounceOutRight{animation-name:bounceOutRight}@keyframes bounceOutUp{20%{transform:translate3d(0,-10px,0)}40%,45%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,20px,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-2000px,0)}}.bounceOutUp{animation-name:bounceOutUp}@keyframes fadeIn{from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}}.fadeIn{animation-name:fadeIn}@keyframes fadeInDown{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInDown{animation-name:fadeInDown}@keyframes fadeInDownBig{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-2000px,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInDownBig{animation-name:fadeInDownBig}@keyframes fadeInLeft{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInLeft{animation-name:fadeInLeft}@keyframes fadeInLeftBig{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-2000px,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInLeftBig{animation-name:fadeInLeftBig}@keyframes fadeInRight{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInRight{animation-name:fadeInRight}@keyframes fadeInRightBig{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(2000px,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInRightBig{animation-name:fadeInRightBig}@keyframes fadeInUp{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,100%,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInUp{animation-name:fadeInUp}@keyframes fadeInUpBig{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInUpBig{animation-name:fadeInUpBig}@keyframes fadeOut{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}.fadeOut{animation-name:fadeOut}@keyframes fadeOutDown{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,100%,0)}}.fadeOutDown{animation-name:fadeOutDown}@keyframes fadeOutDownBig{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)}}.fadeOutDownBig{animation-name:fadeOutDownBig}@keyframes fadeOutLeft{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)}}.fadeOutLeft{animation-name:fadeOutLeft}@keyframes fadeOutLeftBig{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-2000px,0,0)}}.fadeOutLeftBig{animation-name:fadeOutLeftBig}@keyframes fadeOutRight{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0)}}.fadeOutRight{animation-name:fadeOutRight}@keyframes fadeOutRightBig{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(2000px,0,0)}}.fadeOutRightBig{animation-name:fadeOutRightBig}@keyframes fadeOutUp{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)}}.fadeOutUp{animation-name:fadeOutUp}@keyframes fadeOutUpBig{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-2000px,0)}}.fadeOutUpBig{animation-name:fadeOutUpBig}@keyframes flip{from{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,-360deg);animation-timing-function:ease-out}40%{transform:perspective(400px) translate3d(0,0,150px) rotate3d(0,1,0,-190deg);animation-timing-function:ease-out}50%{transform:perspective(400px) translate3d(0,0,150px) rotate3d(0,1,0,-170deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in}80%{transform:perspective(400px) scale3d(.95,.95,.95);animation-timing-function:ease-in}to{transform:perspective(400px);animation-timing-function:ease-in}}.animated.flip{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible;backface-visibility:visible;animation-name:flip}@keyframes flipInX{from{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in;opacity:0}40%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-20deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in}60%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,10deg);opacity:1}80%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-5deg)}to{transform:perspective(400px)}}.flipInX{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important;animation-name:flipInX}@keyframes flipInY{from{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in;opacity:0}40%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,-20deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in}60%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,10deg);opacity:1}80%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,-5deg)}to{transform:perspective(400px)}}.flipInY{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important;animation-name:flipInY}@keyframes flipOutX{from{transform:perspective(400px)}30%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-20deg);opacity:1}to{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);opacity:0}}.flipOutX{animation-name:flipOutX;-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important}@keyframes flipOutY{from{transform:perspective(400px)}30%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,-15deg);opacity:1}to{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);opacity:0}}.flipOutY{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important;animation-name:flipOutY}@keyframes lightSpeedIn{from{transform:translate3d(100%,0,0) skewX(-30deg);opacity:0}60%{transform:skewX(20deg);opacity:1}80%{transform:skewX(-5deg);opacity:1}to{transform:none;opacity:1}}.lightSpeedIn{animation-name:lightSpeedIn;animation-timing-function:ease-out}@keyframes lightSpeedOut{from{opacity:1}to{transform:translate3d(100%,0,0) skewX(30deg);opacity:0}}.lightSpeedOut{animation-name:lightSpeedOut;animation-timing-function:ease-in}@keyframes rotateIn{from{transform-origin:center;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-200deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:center;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateIn{animation-name:rotateIn}@keyframes rotateInDownLeft{from{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-45deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInDownLeft{animation-name:rotateInDownLeft}@keyframes rotateInDownRight{from{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInDownRight{animation-name:rotateInDownRight}@keyframes rotateInUpLeft{from{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInUpLeft{animation-name:rotateInUpLeft}@keyframes rotateInUpRight{from{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-90deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInUpRight{animation-name:rotateInUpRight}@keyframes rotateOut{from{transform-origin:center;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:center;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,200deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOut{animation-name:rotateOut}@keyframes rotateOutDownLeft{from{transform-origin:left bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutDownLeft{animation-name:rotateOutDownLeft}@keyframes rotateOutDownRight{from{transform-origin:right bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-45deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutDownRight{animation-name:rotateOutDownRight}@keyframes rotateOutUpLeft{from{transform-origin:left bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-45deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutUpLeft{animation-name:rotateOutUpLeft}@keyframes rotateOutUpRight{from{transform-origin:right bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,90deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutUpRight{animation-name:rotateOutUpRight}@keyframes hinge{0%{transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}20%,60%{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,80deg);transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}40%,80%{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,60deg);transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;opacity:1}to{transform:translate3d(0,700px,0);opacity:0}}.hinge{animation-name:hinge}@keyframes jackInTheBox{from{opacity:0;transform:scale(.1) rotate(30deg);transform-origin:center bottom}50%{transform:rotate(-10deg)}70%{transform:rotate(3deg)}to{opacity:1;transform:scale(1)}}.jackInTheBox{animation-name:jackInTheBox}@keyframes rollIn{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,-120deg)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.rollIn{animation-name:rollIn}@keyframes rollOut{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,120deg)}}.rollOut{animation-name:rollOut}@keyframes zoomIn{from{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}50%{opacity:1}}.zoomIn{animation-name:zoomIn}@keyframes zoomInDown{from{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,-1000px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInDown{animation-name:zoomInDown}@keyframes zoomInLeft{from{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(-1000px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(10px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInLeft{animation-name:zoomInLeft}@keyframes zoomInRight{from{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(1000px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(-10px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInRight{animation-name:zoomInRight}@keyframes zoomInUp{from{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,1000px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,-60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInUp{animation-name:zoomInUp}@keyframes zoomOut{from{opacity:1}50%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}to{opacity:0}}.zoomOut{animation-name:zoomOut}@keyframes zoomOutDown{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,-60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,2000px,0);transform-origin:center bottom;animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomOutDown{animation-name:zoomOutDown}@keyframes zoomOutLeft{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(42px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale(.1) translate3d(-2000px,0,0);transform-origin:left center}}.zoomOutLeft{animation-name:zoomOutLeft}@keyframes zoomOutRight{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(-42px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale(.1) translate3d(2000px,0,0);transform-origin:right center}}.zoomOutRight{animation-name:zoomOutRight}@keyframes zoomOutUp{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,-2000px,0);transform-origin:center bottom;animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomOutUp{animation-name:zoomOutUp}@keyframes slideInDown{from{transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}}.slideInDown{animation-name:slideInDown}@keyframes slideInLeft{from{transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}}.slideInLeft{animation-name:slideInLeft}@keyframes slideInRight{from{transform:translate3d(100%,0,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}}.slideInRight{animation-name:slideInRight}@keyframes slideInUp{from{transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}}.slideInUp{animation-name:slideInUp}@keyframes slideOutDown{from{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(0,100%,0)}}.slideOutDown{animation-name:slideOutDown}@keyframes slideOutLeft{from{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)}}.slideOutLeft{animation-name:slideOutLeft}@keyframes slideOutRight{from{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0)}}.slideOutRight{animation-name:slideOutRight}@keyframes slideOutUp{from{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)}}.slideOutUp{animation-name:slideOutUp}@font-face{font-family:fontello;src:url(../font/fontello.eot?29612085);src:url(../font/fontello.eot?29612085#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(../font/fontello.woff2?29612085) format('woff2'),url(../font/fontello.woff?29612085) format('woff'),url(../font/fontello.ttf?29612085) format('truetype'),url(../font/fontello.svg?29612085#fontello) format('svg');font-weight:400;font-style:normal}[class*=" icon-"]:before,[class^=icon-]:before{font-family:fontello;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;speak:none;display:inline-block;text-decoration:inherit;width:1em;margin-right:.2em;text-align:center;font-variant:normal;text-transform:none;line-height:1em;margin-left:.2em;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.icon-cancel:before{content:'\e800'}
```

```html
  <button data-animate-start="bounceInRight" data-animate-end="bounceOutRight" 
  data-text-color="white" data-bg-color="red" data-placement="right" 
  data-content="Erreur node Régie" onclick="makeAlert(this)" class="wf-alert-btn">Top Right</button>

  <div id="alertBtns">
  </div>
```

I can figure how I can integrate it into my ajax error event...

Many thank for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I hid your button and changed it to something else

```
<elem data-animate-start="bounceInRight" data-animate-end="bounceOutRight" 
  data-text-color="white" data-bg-color="red" data-placement="right" 
  data-content="Erreur node Régie" class="wf-alert-btn" style="display:none" />
```

Now you can call it

```
makeAlert(document.querySelector("elem"))
```

```js
"use strict";

function makeAlert(t) {
  function e(t, e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      t.classList.remove(n), t.className = "wf-alert-box animated " + o, t.className = "wf-alert-box animated " + o + " transitionTrick"
    }, e), setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("alertBtns").removeChild(a)
    }, e + 1500)
  }
  var a = document.createElement("div"),
    n = (document.createElement("i"), t.getAttribute("data-animate-start")),
    o = t.getAttribute("data-animate-end"),
    r = t.getAttribute("data-text-color"),
    l = t.getAttribute("data-bg-color"),
    i = t.getAttribute("data-placement"),
    c = document.getElementById("alertBtns"),
    d = document.createTextNode(t.getAttribute("data-content"));
  a.className = " wf-alert-box animated " + n, a.appendChild(d), c.appendChild(a), c.className = i, a.style.color = r, a.style.backgroundColor = l, e(a, 3500);
  for (var m = document.querySelectorAll(".wf-alert-box i"), s = 0; s < m.length; s++) m[s].addEventListener("click", function() {
    e(this.parentElement, 0)
  })
}
var topVal = 0,
  alertBoxoffsetHeight = 0,
  alertBoxLastChild = 0,
  alertBoxoffsetTop = 20;

makeAlert(document.querySelector("elem"))
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";.wf-alert-box{max-width:250px;background:#000;padding:30px;color:#fff;position:relative;z-index:9999;text-transform:capitalize;text-align:center;font-weight:700;-webkit-box-shadow:0 29px 77px -23px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-moz-box-shadow:0 29px 77px -23px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 29px 77px -23px rgba(0,0,0,.2);margin-bottom:20px;overflow:hidden;max-height:300px}.wf-alert-box i{position:absolute;top:0;right:0}#alertBtns{position:fixed;max-width:250px}#alertBtns.right{right:25px}#alertBtns.left{left:25px}#alertBtns.center{margin:0 auto;left:0;right:0}.transitionTrick{transition:padding .3s,margin .3s,max-height .1s;-webkit-transition:padding .3s,margin .3s,max-height .1s;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0}.wf-alert-btn{background:#47b2f1;padding:10px 20px;border:0;cursor:pointer;color:#fff;outline:0;box-shadow:0 5px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);-webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);-moz-box-shadow:0 5px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);transition:all .3s;-webkit-transition:all .3s}.wf-alert-btn:hover{box-shadow:0 5px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);-webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);-moz-box-shadow:0 5px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4)}.animated{animation-duration:.5s;animation-fill-mode:both}.animated.infinite{animation-iteration-count:infinite}.animated.hinge{animation-duration:2s}.animated.bounceIn,.animated.bounceOut,.animated.flipOutX,.animated.flipOutY{animation-duration:.75s}@keyframes bounce{20%,53%,80%,from,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}40%,43%{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.755,.050,.855,.060);transform:translate3d(0,-30px,0)}70%{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.755,.050,.855,.060);transform:translate3d(0,-15px,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(0,-4px,0)}}.bounce{animation-name:bounce;transform-origin:center bottom}@keyframes flash{50%,from,to{opacity:1}25%,75%{opacity:0}}.flash{animation-name:flash}@keyframes pulse{from{transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}50%{transform:scale3d(1.05,1.05,1.05)}to{transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}}.pulse{animation-name:pulse}@keyframes rubberBand{from{transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}30%{transform:scale3d(1.25,.75,1)}40%{transform:scale3d(.75,1.25,1)}50%{transform:scale3d(1.15,.85,1)}65%{transform:scale3d(.95,1.05,1)}75%{transform:scale3d(1.05,.95,1)}to{transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}}.rubberBand{animation-name:rubberBand}@keyframes shake{from,to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}10%,30%,50%,70%,90%{transform:translate3d(-10px,0,0)}20%,40%,60%,80%{transform:translate3d(10px,0,0)}}.shake{animation-name:shake}@keyframes headShake{0%{transform:translateX(0)}6.5%{transform:translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg)}18.5%{transform:translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg)}31.5%{transform:translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg)}43.5%{transform:translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg)}50%{transform:translateX(0)}}.headShake{animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;animation-name:headShake}@keyframes swing{20%{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,15deg)}40%{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-10deg)}60%{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,5deg)}80%{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-5deg)}to{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg)}}.swing{transform-origin:top center;animation-name:swing}@keyframes tada{from{transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}10%,20%{transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9) rotate3d(0,0,1,-3deg)}30%,50%,70%,90%{transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1) rotate3d(0,0,1,3deg)}40%,60%,80%{transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1) rotate3d(0,0,1,-3deg)}to{transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}}.tada{animation-name:tada}@keyframes wobble{from{transform:none}15%{transform:translate3d(-25%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,-5deg)}30%{transform:translate3d(20%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,3deg)}45%{transform:translate3d(-15%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,-3deg)}60%{transform:translate3d(10%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,2deg)}75%{transform:translate3d(-5%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,-1deg)}to{transform:none}}.wobble{animation-name:wobble}@keyframes jello{11.1%,from,to{transform:none}22.2%{transform:skewX(-12.5deg) skewY(-12.5deg)}33.3%{transform:skewX(6.25deg) skewY(6.25deg)}44.4%{transform:skewX(-3.125deg) skewY(-3.125deg)}55.5%{transform:skewX(1.5625deg) skewY(1.5625deg)}66.6%{transform:skewX(-.78125deg) skewY(-.78125deg)}77.7%{transform:skewX(.390625deg) skewY(.390625deg)}88.8%{transform:skewX(-.1953125deg) skewY(-.1953125deg)}}.jello{animation-name:jello;transform-origin:center}@keyframes bounceIn{20%,40%,60%,80%,from,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}20%{transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1)}40%{transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(1.03,1.03,1.03)}80%{transform:scale3d(.97,.97,.97)}to{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(1,1,1)}}.bounceIn{animation-name:bounceIn}@keyframes bounceInDown{60%,75%,90%,from,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-3000px,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,25px,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(0,-10px,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(0,5px,0)}to{transform:none}}.bounceInDown{animation-name:bounceInDown}@keyframes bounceInLeft{60%,75%,90%,from,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-3000px,0,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(25px,0,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(-10px,0,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(5px,0,0)}to{transform:none}}.bounceInLeft{animation-name:bounceInLeft}@keyframes bounceInRight{60%,75%,90%,from,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(3000px,0,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(-25px,0,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(10px,0,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(-5px,0,0)}to{transform:none}}.bounceInRight{animation-name:bounceInRight}@keyframes bounceInUp{60%,75%,90%,from,to{animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,3000px,0)}60%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,-20px,0)}75%{transform:translate3d(0,10px,0)}90%{transform:translate3d(0,-5px,0)}to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}}.bounceInUp{animation-name:bounceInUp}@keyframes bounceOut{20%{transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9)}50%,55%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}}.bounceOut{animation-name:bounceOut}@keyframes bounceOutDown{20%{transform:translate3d(0,10px,0)}40%,45%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,-20px,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)}}.bounceOutDown{animation-name:bounceOutDown}@keyframes bounceOutLeft{20%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(20px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-2000px,0,0)}}.bounceOutLeft{animation-name:bounceOutLeft}@keyframes bounceOutRight{20%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(-20px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(2000px,0,0)}}.bounceOutRight{animation-name:bounceOutRight}@keyframes bounceOutUp{20%{transform:translate3d(0,-10px,0)}40%,45%{opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,20px,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-2000px,0)}}.bounceOutUp{animation-name:bounceOutUp}@keyframes fadeIn{from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}}.fadeIn{animation-name:fadeIn}@keyframes fadeInDown{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInDown{animation-name:fadeInDown}@keyframes fadeInDownBig{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-2000px,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInDownBig{animation-name:fadeInDownBig}@keyframes fadeInLeft{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInLeft{animation-name:fadeInLeft}@keyframes fadeInLeftBig{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-2000px,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInLeftBig{animation-name:fadeInLeftBig}@keyframes fadeInRight{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInRight{animation-name:fadeInRight}@keyframes fadeInRightBig{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(2000px,0,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInRightBig{animation-name:fadeInRightBig}@keyframes fadeInUp{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,100%,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInUp{animation-name:fadeInUp}@keyframes fadeInUpBig{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.fadeInUpBig{animation-name:fadeInUpBig}@keyframes fadeOut{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}.fadeOut{animation-name:fadeOut}@keyframes fadeOutDown{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,100%,0)}}.fadeOutDown{animation-name:fadeOutDown}@keyframes fadeOutDownBig{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0)}}.fadeOutDownBig{animation-name:fadeOutDownBig}@keyframes fadeOutLeft{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)}}.fadeOutLeft{animation-name:fadeOutLeft}@keyframes fadeOutLeftBig{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-2000px,0,0)}}.fadeOutLeftBig{animation-name:fadeOutLeftBig}@keyframes fadeOutRight{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0)}}.fadeOutRight{animation-name:fadeOutRight}@keyframes fadeOutRightBig{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(2000px,0,0)}}.fadeOutRightBig{animation-name:fadeOutRightBig}@keyframes fadeOutUp{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)}}.fadeOutUp{animation-name:fadeOutUp}@keyframes fadeOutUpBig{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,-2000px,0)}}.fadeOutUpBig{animation-name:fadeOutUpBig}@keyframes flip{from{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,-360deg);animation-timing-function:ease-out}40%{transform:perspective(400px) translate3d(0,0,150px) rotate3d(0,1,0,-190deg);animation-timing-function:ease-out}50%{transform:perspective(400px) translate3d(0,0,150px) rotate3d(0,1,0,-170deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in}80%{transform:perspective(400px) scale3d(.95,.95,.95);animation-timing-function:ease-in}to{transform:perspective(400px);animation-timing-function:ease-in}}.animated.flip{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible;backface-visibility:visible;animation-name:flip}@keyframes flipInX{from{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in;opacity:0}40%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-20deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in}60%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,10deg);opacity:1}80%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-5deg)}to{transform:perspective(400px)}}.flipInX{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important;animation-name:flipInX}@keyframes flipInY{from{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in;opacity:0}40%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,-20deg);animation-timing-function:ease-in}60%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,10deg);opacity:1}80%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,-5deg)}to{transform:perspective(400px)}}.flipInY{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important;animation-name:flipInY}@keyframes flipOutX{from{transform:perspective(400px)}30%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-20deg);opacity:1}to{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);opacity:0}}.flipOutX{animation-name:flipOutX;-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important}@keyframes flipOutY{from{transform:perspective(400px)}30%{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,-15deg);opacity:1}to{transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);opacity:0}}.flipOutY{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible!important;backface-visibility:visible!important;animation-name:flipOutY}@keyframes lightSpeedIn{from{transform:translate3d(100%,0,0) skewX(-30deg);opacity:0}60%{transform:skewX(20deg);opacity:1}80%{transform:skewX(-5deg);opacity:1}to{transform:none;opacity:1}}.lightSpeedIn{animation-name:lightSpeedIn;animation-timing-function:ease-out}@keyframes lightSpeedOut{from{opacity:1}to{transform:translate3d(100%,0,0) skewX(30deg);opacity:0}}.lightSpeedOut{animation-name:lightSpeedOut;animation-timing-function:ease-in}@keyframes rotateIn{from{transform-origin:center;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-200deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:center;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateIn{animation-name:rotateIn}@keyframes rotateInDownLeft{from{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-45deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInDownLeft{animation-name:rotateInDownLeft}@keyframes rotateInDownRight{from{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInDownRight{animation-name:rotateInDownRight}@keyframes rotateInUpLeft{from{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInUpLeft{animation-name:rotateInUpLeft}@keyframes rotateInUpRight{from{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-90deg);opacity:0}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:none;opacity:1}}.rotateInUpRight{animation-name:rotateInUpRight}@keyframes rotateOut{from{transform-origin:center;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:center;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,200deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOut{animation-name:rotateOut}@keyframes rotateOutDownLeft{from{transform-origin:left bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutDownLeft{animation-name:rotateOutDownLeft}@keyframes rotateOutDownRight{from{transform-origin:right bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-45deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutDownRight{animation-name:rotateOutDownRight}@keyframes rotateOutUpLeft{from{transform-origin:left bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:left bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,-45deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutUpLeft{animation-name:rotateOutUpLeft}@keyframes rotateOutUpRight{from{transform-origin:right bottom;opacity:1}to{transform-origin:right bottom;transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,90deg);opacity:0}}.rotateOutUpRight{animation-name:rotateOutUpRight}@keyframes hinge{0%{transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}20%,60%{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,80deg);transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}40%,80%{transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,60deg);transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;opacity:1}to{transform:translate3d(0,700px,0);opacity:0}}.hinge{animation-name:hinge}@keyframes jackInTheBox{from{opacity:0;transform:scale(.1) rotate(30deg);transform-origin:center bottom}50%{transform:rotate(-10deg)}70%{transform:rotate(3deg)}to{opacity:1;transform:scale(1)}}.jackInTheBox{animation-name:jackInTheBox}@keyframes rollIn{from{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,-120deg)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}.rollIn{animation-name:rollIn}@keyframes rollOut{from{opacity:1}to{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,120deg)}}.rollOut{animation-name:rollOut}@keyframes zoomIn{from{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}50%{opacity:1}}.zoomIn{animation-name:zoomIn}@keyframes zoomInDown{from{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,-1000px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInDown{animation-name:zoomInDown}@keyframes zoomInLeft{from{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(-1000px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(10px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInLeft{animation-name:zoomInLeft}@keyframes zoomInRight{from{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(1000px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(-10px,0,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInRight{animation-name:zoomInRight}@keyframes zoomInUp{from{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,1000px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}60%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,-60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomInUp{animation-name:zoomInUp}@keyframes zoomOut{from{opacity:1}50%{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}to{opacity:0}}.zoomOut{animation-name:zoomOut}@keyframes zoomOutDown{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,-60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,2000px,0);transform-origin:center bottom;animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomOutDown{animation-name:zoomOutDown}@keyframes zoomOutLeft{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(42px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale(.1) translate3d(-2000px,0,0);transform-origin:left center}}.zoomOutLeft{animation-name:zoomOutLeft}@keyframes zoomOutRight{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(-42px,0,0)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale(.1) translate3d(2000px,0,0);transform-origin:right center}}.zoomOutRight{animation-name:zoomOutRight}@keyframes zoomOutUp{40%{opacity:1;transform:scale3d(.475,.475,.475) translate3d(0,60px,0);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19)}to{opacity:0;transform:scale3d(.1,.1,.1) translate3d(0,-2000px,0);transform-origin:center bottom;animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1)}}.zoomOutUp{animation-name:zoomOutUp}@keyframes slideInDown{from{transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}}.slideInDown{animation-name:slideInDown}@keyframes slideInLeft{from{transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}}.slideInLeft{animation-name:slideInLeft}@keyframes slideInRight{from{transform:translate3d(100%,0,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}}.slideInRight{animation-name:slideInRight}@keyframes slideInUp{from{transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);visibility:visible}to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}}.slideInUp{animation-name:slideInUp}@keyframes slideOutDown{from{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(0,100%,0)}}.slideOutDown{animation-name:slideOutDown}@keyframes slideOutLeft{from{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)}}.slideOutLeft{animation-name:slideOutLeft}@keyframes slideOutRight{from{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0)}}.slideOutRight{animation-name:slideOutRight}@keyframes slideOutUp{from{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}to{visibility:hidden;transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)}}.slideOutUp{animation-name:slideOutUp}@font-face{font-family:fontello;src:url(../font/fontello.eot?29612085);src:url(../font/fontello.eot?29612085#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(../font/fontello.woff2?29612085) format('woff2'),url(../font/fontello.woff?29612085) format('woff'),url(../font/fontello.ttf?29612085) format('truetype'),url(../font/fontello.svg?29612085#fontello) format('svg');font-weight:400;font-style:normal}[class*=" icon-"]:before,[class^=icon-]:before{font-family:fontello;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;speak:none;display:inline-block;text-decoration:inherit;width:1em;margin-right:.2em;text-align:center;font-variant:normal;text-transform:none;line-height:1em;margin-left:.2em;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.icon-cancel:before{content:'\e800'}
```

```html
<div id="alertBtns"></div>

<elem data-animate-start="bounceInRight" data-animate-end="bounceOutRight" 
  data-text-color="white" data-bg-color="red" data-placement="right" 
  data-content="Erreur node Régie" class="wf-alert-btn" style="display:none" />
```

Comment: Many Thanks ! I found how to integrate it into my webapp ! Just cannot figure how to modify the delay before the popup bounce out, but it will come :) .